# Can we say that a limit exists at a discontinuity?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Is it correct to say that $\lim_{x \to 0}x^x$ doesn't exist whereas $\lim_{x \to 0^+}x^x$ does? I think so but someone told be that the former should be interpreted as the latter. I think it's incorrect because it's not a limit unless it's both-sided or sidedness is clearly stated.

$\lim_{x \to 0}x^x \neq 1$

$\lim_{x \to 0^-}x^x \neq 1$

$\lim_{x \to 0^+}x^x = 1$

The domain is not $\mathbb{R}^+$. The function is defined for certain negative real numbers as well.

$\lim_{x \to 0}x^x=1 \Longleftrightarrow \forall_{\epsilon>0} \ \exists_{\delta>0}\  \forall_{x\in B(0,\delta) \cap Dom\ f} \ \left|x^x-1 \right|<\epsilon$. Not true.

The contents of the modulus can be arbitrarily close to zero, but also arbitrarily close to two. Therefore this limit does not exist.

$\forall_{\epsilon>0} \ \exists_{\delta>0}\  \forall_{x\in B(0,\delta) \cap Dom\ f} \ \left|x^x-1 \right|<\epsilon \ \vee \ \left|x^x+1 \right|<\epsilon.$ This is true.

Comment: Hint: What is the domain of $x^x$?

Comment: In my personal view, $\lim_{x\to 0}$ (without any $+$ or $-$) just means "from all directions where the expression makes sense to evaluate", and thus it's defined in this case. But conventions may differ on this, and I'm no authority.

Comment: I agree with Arthur.

Comment: It may depend on how you define $a^b$ when $a$ is negative real and $b$ is not an integer

Comment: The common definition of limit is: $$\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)=L\Longleftrightarrow \forall\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}^+ \exists\delta\in\mathbb{R}^+ \text{ such that if } x\in B(x_0,\delta)\cap\operatorname{Dom}f \text{ then } |f(x)-L|<\epsilon$$ so the limit is always aproached on the domain of the function, otherwise it doesn't make sense to consider "$f(x)$".

Comment: Doesn't $x^x$ just have a super complicated domain for $x<0$ , the expression evaluates to a real number for $x=-\frac 1{101}$ but not for $x=-\frac 1{100}$

Comment: This is really a matter of definitions. As other comments are pointing out, the question is whether you define "limit" (without sidedness qualification) such that the existence of the limit at $0$ requires the function to be defined for an interval of negative values of $x$ near zero. Many calculus books do adopt this type of definition, but other sources do not.

Comment: If you give special treatment to rational powers so that $(-1/3)^(-1/3)$ is a real number, and your domain for $x^x$ includes every $x$ for which $x^x$ is real, the negative elements of the domain are rational numbers that can be written with odd denominators. In any neighborhood of any of these numbers there will be some $x$ such that $x^x < -1$ and some $x$ such that $x^x > 1,$ so the function is discontinuous at all negative numbers in its domain as well as at zero. Is that the kind of answer you're looking for?

Comment: Well, to answer the titular question; of course limits can exist at points of discontinuity; for consider the function defined by $(\sin x)/x$ everywhere except for $x=0,$ where we define it to be $0.$ Then the function is discontinuous at the origin, but the limit exists there.